# highcharts: update data keys with animation

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts, transition

I recently found out that it is possible in highcharts to map and re-map entries of `series.data` to different properties of a chart which is great. However, one issue i have with this technique is that those changes are not always animated.

For example, the following function switches between column 2 an 3 to be used as the y coordinate in a bar chart by re-mapping the data keys. When the chart is updated the widths of the bars uses no easing. Instead, they just jump from the old `y` position to the new one.

```js
let keys_toggle = false, 
    keys1 = ["name", "y", "y2"],
    keys2 = ["name", "y2", "y"];
function switch_series() {
    keys_toggle = !keys_toggle;
    let keys = keys_toggle ? keys1 : keys2, 
        chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
    chart.update({plotOptions:{series:{keys: keys }}});
}
```

Full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/GregorDeCillia/rxk8L2v0/93/

Is there a way to configure this in a way such that the transitions between the bars are animated in the same way as in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/)? The reason I'm preferring re-mapping of columns instead of using multiple series is that this makes the data very managable for large drilldown charts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately under the hood, Highcharts creates points from scratch when you update the `keys` property, which prevents animation. I suggest using the `setData` method and mapping your data. For example:

```
let keys_toggle = false;

function switch_series() {
  keys_toggle = !keys_toggle;
  const chart = Highcharts.charts[0];

  chart.series[0].setData(getData(keys_toggle ? 1 : 2));
}

const data = [
  ['Chrome', 63.06, 6.3, 'Chrome'],
  ['Safari', 19.84, 2.7],
  ['Firefox', 4.18, 3.8],
  ['Edge', 4.12, 3.2],
  ['Opera', 2.33, 1.8],
  ['Internet Explorer', 0.45, 2.7],
  ['Other', 1.582, 1]
];

const getData = (skippedIndex) => {
  return data.map(
    dataEl => dataEl.filter((el, i) => i !== skippedIndex)
  )
}

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    name: 'Browsers',
    data: getData(2)
  }],
  ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pjkv7hya/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: Thank you for these insights on how highcharts works under the hood. I considered using `setData()` but wasn't happy with the fact that (a) the drilldown level gets reset and (b) the drilldown series are unaffected by this update. My basic idea was to preserve the drilldown level when the series is switched and preserve the selected series when a drillup/drilldown happens. I guess this would require some more complicated setup using drillup/drilldown callbacks?

Comment: Hi @Gregor de Cillia, You can also use `chart.update` - please check: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rdhtL2x0/ However, if you don't want to update the drilled-down series, you need to add some additional check, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x476k3uL/